# S3 Bucket - setting policy to "acknowledge that existing objects with the same name will be overwritten."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have suspended object versioning on my S3 Bucket, but I don't want to have to select the check box that says "I acknowledge that existing objects with the same name will be overwritten" every time I upload photos to the s3 bucket.

I successfully set up an S3 Bucket Policy to make it so I don't have to specify that I want the uploads to be publicly viewable on every upload.  Is there also an S3 Bucket Policy I can set to bypass the checkmark as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is there also an S3 Bucket Policy I can set to bypass the checkmark as well?

Sadly, this is new S3 console future. It is **not related to the bucket policies**.

You can use **AWS CLI or SDK** to upload objects "peacefully", without any distractions if you want to skip all the S3 console steps.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded and used S3 Browser and it worked great. Thank you!